# Image preview overflow the browser height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Using image preview plugin, I need the preview automatically goes up when the thumbnail is almost way to the bottom of the screen. I tried this code, but it doesn't work well.

```
if((e.pageX <= $(document).width()/2) && (e.pageY <= $(document).height()*0.75)) {
    $("#preview")
        .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
        .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px");
} else if((e.pageX > $(document).width()/2) && (e.pageY <= $(document).height()*0.75)) {
    $("#preview")
        .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
        .css("right",($(document).width() - e.pageX + yOffset) + "px");         
} else if((e.pageX <= $(document).width()/2) && (e.pageY > $(document).height()*0.75)) {
        .css("bottom",($(window).height() - e.pageY + xOffset) + "px")
        .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px");
} else {
    $("#preview")
        .css("bottom",($(window).height() - e.pageY + xOffset) + "px")
        .css("right",($(document).width() - e.pageX + yOffset) + "px");         
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work well? What do you mean? That you are missing `$('#preview')` at your seconds `else if`?

Comment: Sorry, it got deleted when editing it here. By doesn't work well, I meant the one at the bottom is intermittenly shown up. When showing up, it's still overflowing the screen bottom.

Comment: can you show an example? like a fiddle, or a link?